# How are Bitmaps stored in memory in .NET?

Tags: .net, image, performance, architecture, bitmap

In .NET you usually use the Bitmap class to store images. To access it quickly, you need to call [lock() and unlock()](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp) to copy the contents of the bitmap into memory. So, does it mean that the bitmap was not stored in a packed memory array before locking?

Exactly what is the need for locking?, i.e. why couldn't the platform simply return a pointer to the first pixel of the bitmap and let you access the pixels directly? (apart from the "unsafe" memory access considerations)

Some possible reasons:

- The bitmap is stored in its original compressed form to save memory (PNG, JPEG, etc)
- The bitmap is stored in 24-bpp format so its slower to access than a 32-bpp image
- The bitmap is not stored in a packed memory array and is fragmented so can't be read/written fast
- The bitmap is stored in an undisclosed manner, and the platform does not want you to access the actual bitmap data memory - forcing you to create a copy of it in memory using lock()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bitmaps are read in a lazy fashion.  The actual algorithm used depends a great deal on the image format, a .bmp file is easy, a .jpeg is not so easy.  Under the hood, GDI+ creates a memory mapped file to map the file data into RAM, when necessary, taking advantage of the demand-paged virtual memory mapping feature of the operating system.  It is this MMF that infamously creates a lock on the file and is responsible for the ratty exceptions you get when trying to save an image back to a file with the same name.

Bitmap.LockBits() creates a separate buffer that maps the pixel data from the MMF to an area in memory that has the requested pixel format.  Now you have the data in a well defined format that's independent from the format in the file.  Calling UnlockBits() writes the modified data back, if any.  Exactly how the data from the file gets re-combined with the modified pixels is not specified and is likely to depend a great deal on the codec.

This exact same locking happens, unseen, when you use the bitmap in other methods.  Like when you draw the image with Graphics.DrawImage().  And infamously when you use Bitmap.GetPixel().  As you can guess by now, there's a fair amount of overhead involved in getting the pixel data converted at the lock call, the reason that GetPixel() is so slow since you do it for every pixel in the bitmap rather than just once, as DrawImage and LockBits() do.

It should be also clear that the amount of overhead depends a great deal on the image file format, the expense of decoding the pixel data on-the-fly, the amount of caching done by the decoder, the pixel format of the file versus the pixel format you ask for in LockBits().  There's way too much going on here to make predictable perf guesses, you'll have to profile it.

Comment: Incredible info, Hans! However, one question: If the bitmap must be rendered to screen at some point does it make sense to "lock" the bitmap into memory once, and then preform all computations on the memory and use the memory for rendering too? (considering I'm writing my own bitmap renderer?)

Comment: Yes, it make sense to convert the pixel format of the bitmap to a format that's compatible with the video adapter.  So the pixel data can be blasted directly into video memory without conversion.  On any modern adapter that's 32bppPArgb, it is *ten* times faster than any of the other ones.

Comment: Is 32bpp ARGB the fastest format even when working with low-level apps written in C++? "ccxvii" says that BGRA is the fastest and native format for video/graphics cards - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/44153/15277

Comment: No, it is 32bppPArgb.  Pre-multiplied alpha is important so that the alpha effect doesn't have to be applied when it is sent to the video adapter.  BGRA is not relevant, it is not a pixel format supported by the Bitmap class.  And otherwise just a endian-ness word, little vs big.  Bitmap already puts them in the right order.

Answer (score 3):

> The bitmap is stored in an undisclosed manner, and the platform does not want you to access the actual bitmap data memory - forcing you to create a copy of it in memory using lock()

This, I think. The bitmap is stored in GDI, and every call to `GetPixel()` will become a call to `GdipBitmapGetPixel()` in [`gdiplus.dll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[`Bitmap.LockBits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which calls `Bitmap::Lockbits` in GDI, will return all pixels held by GDI for the given image at once, as a managed `BitmapData` object.

Documentation for [`Bitmap::Lockbits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> locks a rectangular portion of this bitmap and provides a temporary buffer that you can use to read or write pixel data in a specified format. Any pixel data that you write to the buffer is copied to the Bitmap object when you call Bitmap::UnlockBits.

In the GDI documentation I cannot find any other way to access the 'raw' bitmap, so I think this is because of the way GDI was designed (perhaps because of the device-dependant way GDI stores bitmaps in (video?) memory?), so you *have* to call `LockBits` if you want to operate on the 'raw' bitmap data.

Answer (score 1):

> why couldn't the platform simply return a pointer to the first pixel of the bitmap and let you access the pixels directly?

Just an idea: all image data ("pixels") can be stored on video card's memory (not CPU's memory). So, there is no direct access to image data from CPU/application. As the result, there should be a special way to get such access to image data from CPU by request. Like a `LockBits/UnockBits`.