# GDI+ error when loading a high resolution JPG

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, gdi+

I met the common GDI+ error when trying to load a JPG image by C#. I am not sure if it is due to the high resolution of this JPG (46495px*4536px) because loading other low resolution JPG files works fine. The issue JPG file size is  4696KB.

Code:

```
var newImage = Image.FromFile("demo.jpg"); //issue jpg
```

It also failed when using Image.FromStream() API:

```
var stream = File.OpenRead("demo.jpg");

var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Much appreciation if anyone could help explain

Comment: Hi, what is the error message that you get?

Comment: I suspect you're hitting a limitation of GDI+/.NET that the max object size allowed on the GC Heap is 2GB even on a 64bit OS. I'm not knowledgeable enough to give an answer, but there's some interesting reading from the man himself Hans Passant on this subject: [How are Bitmaps stored in memory in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495382/how-are-bitmaps-stored-in-memory-in-net) and [What is the maximum resolution of C# .NET Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495382/how-are-bitmaps-stored-in-memory-in-net)

Comment: The error Message is: "A Generic Eror Occures at GDI+" and errorCode is -2147467259.

Comment: There's no hint about the limitation or any out of memory issue from Visual Studio.

Comment: Practically all errors returned by GDI+ are nondescript like that, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the available RAM to store the decompressed image bitmap

On a 32bit display you will require `width * height * 4 + c` bytes free, where `c` is unknown depending on the implementation of the drawing classes used.

**Example**

In your specific case, the calculation is as follows:

```
46495 * 4536 * 4 + c = 843605280 bytes + c = 805mb + c
```

Use the following to see how much memory is available for your bitmap.

Include a reference to the VisualBasic dll:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
```

The method is as follows:

```
Console.Out.Write(new ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory + "bytes free");
```

...or...

```
Console.Out.Write((ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory / 1048576) + "mb free");
```

**Find c**

To find `c`, use the method above both before AND after an image load.

By loading a number of images successfully and recording the memory used before and after the load.

Experiment by comparing the memory used before and after loading different sizes of image, taking into account the size of the bitmap and you will discover a close approximation of `c`.

Be aware that all image types are converted to a raw bitmap internally for viewing, regardless of whether it's stored as a .jpg, .png, .gif or whatever. So when I say Bitmp, I'm not referring to the extension .bmp. Instead, I am referring to a bitmp in a literal sense as a raw image file i.e. a map of bits.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the elaborate answer. Applied above method to see available memory.\r\n Result:  8191mb free. A lot of free space than 805mb. So in this case, it seems not related to the RAM, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

the GDI+ will throw an "OutOfMemoryException" if it does not support the pixel format of the file.

Comment: not "OutOfMemoryException" error message from Visual Studio. It just throw "A Generic Error occurs at GDI+" and ErrorCode is  -2147467259